# How do I retrieve the current sample play position from an XAudio2 source voice?

Tags: windows, directx, xaudio2

I have an `IXAudio2SourceVoice` that is playing a submitted `XAUDIO2_BUFFER`. How do I retrieve from these the play position within the currently-playing buffer, in samples?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `IXAudio2SourceVoice::GetState`:

```
    XAUDIO2_VOICE_STATE xstate;
#if (_WIN32_WINNT >= _WIN32_WINNT_WIN8)
    voice->GetState( &xstate, 0 );
#else
    voice->GetState( &xstate );
#endif
if ( xstate.BuffersQueued > 0 )
{
    // xstate.SamplesPlayed
}
```

> The reason `GetState` takes a flag in XAudio 2.8 or later is specifically so you can use `XAUDIO2_VOICE_NOSAMPLESPLAYED` to save the overhead of filling out the current `SamplesPlayed` value.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Is there anything special I need to do to get SamplesPlayed to work? It's always returning 0, and I'm definitely *not* passing the XAUDIO2_VOICE_NOSAMPLESPLAYED flag.

Comment: Hmm.. SamplesPlayed is working fine in a simpler test program I made, so I must have screwed up my logic somewhere. Anyway, it looks like this answer is correct. Thanks!